# IBAction stops working when I connect IBOutlet

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an IBAction wired up to a button in my storyboard that plays a sound. This works just fine. However, when I wire up an IBOutlet to the same button, the code for the outlet takes over and the IBAction stops working. In this case, the IBOutlet serves the purpose of making the button pulse with animation. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import AVFoundation

class Page1: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var testpulse: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ahh", withExtension: "mp3")

        do {
            ahh = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
            ahh.prepareToPlay()

        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }

        testpulse.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Page1.addPulse))
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        testpulse.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


    }

    @objc func addPulse(){
        let pulse = Pulsing(numberOfPulses: 1, radius: 110, position: testpulse.center)
        pulse.animationDuration = 0.8
        pulse.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(pulse, below: testpulse.layer)
    }

    @IBAction func ahh(_ sender: Any) {
        ahh.play()
    }  
}
```

And for my Swift animation file I have this:

```
import UIKit

class Pulsing: CALayer {

    var animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()

    var initialPulseScale:Float = 0
    var nextPulseAfter:TimeInterval = 0
    var animationDuration:TimeInterval = 1.5
    var radius:CGFloat = 200
    var numberOfPulses:Float = Float.infinity

    override init(layer: Any) {
        super.init(layer: layer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init (numberOfPulses:Float = Float.infinity, radius:CGFloat, position:CGPoint) {
        super.init()

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        self.opacity = 0
        self.radius = radius
        self.numberOfPulses = numberOfPulses
        self.position = position

        self.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
        //self.cornerRadius = radius

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
            self.setupAnimationGroup()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.add(self.animationGroup, forKey: "pulse")
            }
        }

        setupAnimationGroup()

        self.add(animationGroup, forKey: "pulse")
    }

    func createScaleAnimation () -> CABasicAnimation {
        let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
        scaleAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: initialPulseScale)
        scaleAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 1)
        scaleAnimation.duration = animationDuration

        return scaleAnimation
    }

    func createOpacityAnimation() -> CAKeyframeAnimation? {

        let opacityAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        opacityAnimation.duration = animationDuration
        opacityAnimation.values = [0.4, 0.8, 0]
        opacityAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.2, 1]

        return opacityAnimation
    }

    func setupAnimationGroup() {
        self.animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        self.animationGroup.duration = animationDuration + nextPulseAfter
        self.animationGroup.repeatCount = numberOfPulses

        let defaultCurve = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault)
        self.animationGroup.timingFunction = defaultCurve

        self.animationGroup.animations = [createScaleAnimation(), createOpacityAnimation()!]
    }
}
```

When I connect the IBAction to my button, the sound works. However when I connect the IBOutlet, the animation works but the IBAction doesn't. What could be causing this? It's still connected in the storyboard.

Comment: Why do you use a separate gesture recognizer for pulsing? Why not call "addPulse" in your "ahh" method?

Comment: get class before you perform action using `if sender.isKind(of: UIButton)` or set the class to `UIButton` instead of `Any`  in your action method.

Comment: Your problem likely does not come from adding the IBOutlet, but rather from the gesture recognizer. You're telling the button to respond to a tap one way in the IBAction connection and a different way in code.

Comment: I had a hunch it was the gesture recognizer. I'm trying to create an IBAction from the animation code but I'm not quite sure how to do that because I followed a tutorial for this initially. I'm sure there's something I need to call in my method like Olter suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import AVFoundation

class Page1: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var testpulse: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ahh", withExtension: "mp3")

        do {
            ahh = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
            ahh.prepareToPlay()

        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }

        testpulse.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func addPulse(){
        let pulse = Pulsing(numberOfPulses: 1, radius: 110, position: testpulse.center)
        pulse.animationDuration = 0.8
        pulse.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(pulse, below: testpulse.layer)
    }

    @IBAction func ahh(_ sender: Any) {
        ahh.play()
        addPulse()
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see the goal here is to recognize multiple gesture recognizers. I tried this code and it pretty much works the same unfortunately. I haven't used extensions before. Do you put that before the class? That was the only place I could put it without getting any errors.

Comment: I have edited my answer, just copy paste instead of your class

Comment: Hey, this worked! I knew it should've been this simple. Still, it took me a little bit to get it working. Thank you so much.